# How to obtain MatchingAccountVerificationData after successful user verification via Fastlink IAV widget?

Tags: yodlee

I'm trying to obtain MatchingAccountVerificationData from Yodlee IAV `getMatchingAccountVerificationData`
for user that was verified via fastlink widget.

The only missing piece for me is how to obtain `verifiableAccount.verifiableAccountId` so
I could make use of that API.

I would know how to get that data without fastlink, because that information
appears in response to `addTransferAccountForItem` as "dfiAccountId".
The problem is that fastlink widget handles that so we're not aware of transferaccount ids.

It is possible to get list of transferaccount / verifiableaccounts per user
so we'll be able to MatchingAccountVerificationData?

How to do it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Though, this is not documented but you can use getAllTransferAccounts API
Below is the informaiton for the same-

Endpoint(You can replace your environment specific base URL)- https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0/jsonsdk/TransferAccountManagement/getAllTransferAccounts

HTTP: POST

Input parameter needs to be passed-

1. cobSessionToken
2. userSessionToken

This will give you list of all added accounts' **dfiAccountId** and **transferAccountId**.